# How do I print out the unique words of an inputted string?

Tags: python

I'm struggling to print out the unique words of the phrase a user inputs. The function `get_count_of_unique_words()` doesn't seem to work. When a user inputs their chosen phrase or words, it needs to print out any unique or repeated words in that phrase.

```
from collections import Counter

user_text = input("Please enter some text --> ")


def word_count(user_text):
    return(len(user_text.strip().split(" ")))


number_of_characters = len(user_text)


def get_count_of_unique_words(user_text):
    selected_words = []
    for word in user_text:
        if word.isalpha():
           selected_words.append(word)

    unique_count = 0
    for letter, count in Counter(selected_words).items():
        if count == 1:
            unique_count += 1


print("You typed", number_of_characters, "characters")
print("You typed", word_count(user_text), "words")
print("There are", get_count_of_unique_words(user_text),"unique words")
```

Comment: instead to count unique elements  you can create a set:  `set(your_list)`

Comment: Your first for loop should start `for word in user_text.split()` instead, unless you're actually trying to count letters instead of words

Comment: Your [mre] is neither minimal nor complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing `user_text` to the function, try creating a list of `words` that can be reused for both the word count and the unique words. Then, just get the unique elements in that list by converting it to a set and getting the length of the set. Like this:

```
user_text = input("Please enter some text --> ")

words = user_text.strip().split(' ')

print("You typed", len(user_text), "characters")
print("You typed", len(words), "words")
print("There are", len(set(words)), "unique words")
```

You could extract each of these statements into their own function, although you don't need to. I chose not to because it makes the code a bit cleaner and shorter.